# operations on elements inside lists in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am writing a prolog code and in the middle i want to check is all the elements in a list are a not included in a certain predicate

```
Here is the code:
 trap(a).
 trap(b).

not_trap([A|B]):-
\+trap(A),
not_trap(B).

not_trap(B):-
\+trap(B).
```

but this wont work can anyone tell me where I went wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your base case is wrong. Whatever list you give to this predicate will be classified as not containing a trap, since the second clause matches it:

```
?- trace.
true.

[trace]  ?- not_trap([a]).
   Call: (6) not_trap([a]) ? creep
   Call: (7) trap(a) ? creep
   Exit: (7) trap(a) ? creep
   Call: (7) trap([a]) ? creep
   Fail: (7) trap([a]) ? creep
   Exit: (6) not_trap([a]) ? creep
true.
```

You can fix this predicate by either using the typical list recursion base case of

```
not_trap([]).
```

or by rewriting it without explicit recursion as

```
not_trap(L) :-
    \+ (member(X, L), trap(X)).
```

(Read this as: there is no member `X` of `L` that is a trap.)

Comment: or even forall(member(X, L), \+ trap(X)).

Comment: @Mog: judging by the SWI-Prolog manual, `forall` does not seem to be an ISO standard predicate.

Comment: @larsmans yup, but seems like most prologs have it nowadays anyway.